# Prove the compact set with open cover

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Question is

**Show that $(0,1]$ is not compact by constructing an open cover of $(0,1]$ that does not have a finite sub-cover**

can we choose the open cover $Q_n = (1/n,1]$, $n=2,3 \ldots$ so (

> i choose another $Q_n$ after your comment

)
there is no finite open cover for $(0,1]$

is this reasonable prove?

Comment: The example is not a cover, no set of it includes $1$.

Comment: $\{(r,1]:0<r<1\}$

Comment: Use $\left(\frac{1}{n},17\right)$, where $n$ ranges over all integers $\ge 2$.

Comment: If you show the one infinite open cover this prove is done to prove that there is no finite open cover?

Answer (score 2):

Choose $\displaystyle Q_n = \bigg(\frac1n, 2\bigg)$ for $n = 2, 3, \ldots$. Notice that $\displaystyle (0, 1] \subseteq \bigcup_{k = 2}^\infty Q_n$ so the $Q_n$ form an open cover.

Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $\{Q_n\}$ has a finite-subcover, say $Q_{k_1}, \ldots, Q_{k_n}$.

Choose $k = \max\{k_1, \ldots, k_n\}$ and observe that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i = 1}^n Q_{k_i} = (1/k, 2)$.

Notice that $1/(k + 1) \notin (1/k, 2)$, but $1/(k + 1) \in (0, 1]$.

Hence we have found an open cover that does not have a finite subcover.